# Can't seem to get my method (in Java) to compile correctly

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to figure out exactly what is wrong with my winorTie method in this little tictacttoe game I am trying to create.  Would anyone be able to help?  Thanks

```
package tictactoegame;

/**
 *
 * @author Douglas Boulden
 */
public class tictactoegame {

    static int [][] gameboard;
    static final int EMPTY = 0;
    static final int NOUGHT = -1;
    static final int CROSS = 1;

    static void set (int val, int row) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int col = 0;
        if (gameboard[row][col] == EMPTY)
                gameboard[row][col] = val;
        else throw new
            IllegalArgumentException("Player already there!");
    }

    static void displayBoard () {
        for (int[] gameboard1 : gameboard) {
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int c = 0; c < gameboard1.length; c++) {
                switch (gameboard1[c]) {
                    case NOUGHT:
                        System.out.print("0");
                        break;
                    case CROSS:
                        System.out.print("X");
                        break;
                    default:           //Empty
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println("\n------\n");
        }
    }

    static void createBoard(int rows, int cols) {
        gameboard = new int [rows] [cols];
    }

    static int winOrTie() {
       if (gameboard [0][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard [0][-1])
           return NOUGHT;
    } else if (gameboard [0][0] == && CROSS) [0][1]  {
           return CROSS;
    } else if (gameboard [0][0]== && " "()) [0][0] {    
           return 0;
    } else {
           return false;                
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        createBoard(3,3);
        int turn = 0;
        int playerVal;
        int outcome;
        java.util.Scanner scan = new
            java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            displayBoard();
            playerVal = (turn % 2 == 0)? NOUGHT : CROSS;
            if (playerVal == NOUGHT) {
                System.out.println ("\n-0's turn-");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n-X's turn-");
                }
            System.out.print("Enter row and Column:");
            try {
                set(playerVal, scan.nextInt());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
            {System.err.println(ex);}
            turn ++;
            outcome = winOrTie();
        } while ( outcome == -2 );
        displayBoard();
        switch (outcome) {
            case NOUGHT:
                System.out.println("0 wins!");
                break;
            case CROSS:
                System.out.println("X wins!");
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Tie.");
                break;
            }
     }

}
```

Comment: What does `gameboard [0][-1]` mean?  What does `" "()` mean?

Comment: Please use IDE to write code. In the function `winOrTie()` why there is a `}` in front of the first `else if` condition? What is the meaning of this line `else if (gameboard [0][0] == && CROSS) [0][1]`?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: This line is one of your errors: `if (gameboard [0][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard [0][-1])`.  After the `&&` must come an expression that evaluates to a boolean value, whereas you've provided `gameboard[0][-1]`, and then there's the problem  that you're using a negative index into an array, which will cause a runtime error, even if you can get it to compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this was mentioned in the comments, but these conditions fundamentally don't make sense:

```
if (gameboard [0][0] == NOUGHT && gameboard [0][-1])
       return NOUGHT;
} else if (gameboard [0][0] == && CROSS) [0][1]  {
       return CROSS;
} else if (gameboard [0][0]== && " "()) [0][0] {    
       return 0;
```

For example, what do you think that `if (gameboard [0][0] == && CROSS) [0][1]` is supposed to do? What exactly is `" "()` supposed to be? And what do you think that `== &&` does? It's difficult to know exactly what you were actually trying to achieve here.

Also, consider `gameboard [0][-1]`. There are two problems here. First, you do realize that -1 isn't actually a valid array index in Java, right? (That's allowable in Python, but not Java). Also, `gameboard [0][-1]` is an integer, not a bool, so `&& gameboard [0][-1]` doesn't make sense. If you have something like `A && B`, both `A` and `B` *must* evaluate to some kind of boolean value (i.e. `true` or `false`).

Also, I'd encourage you not to do indentation like you have here. I'd recommend putting each "else if" on its own line.

Comment: I am attempting to define the winortie method.  I need to find out did X win if so what value, did O win if so what value, did a Tie happen if so what value, are there empty cells on the game board if so what value.

Comment: @Doug Can you clarify what you think that those should do? Quite bluntly, the syntax for the if statements listed above is virtually incoherent - for example, what the heck is `else if (gameboard [0][0]== && " "()) [0][0]` supposed to do?

Comment: Believe me I know they are incoherent.  The if statements I have are not right at all.  That's why I'm on here.  If I can get help with the winortie method and get it correct, this project will compile correctly

Comment: @Doug Can you explain what you wanted them to do? For example, what condition did you want `else if (gameboard [0][0]== && " "()) [0][0]` to express?

Comment: If the code is correct in the winortie method it is supposed to look like this in the output...

Comment: It is supposed to look like this... 

|||| 
------- 
|||| 
------- 
|||| 
------- 
--O’s turn-- 
|O| | | 
------- 
|||| 
------- 
|||| 
------- 
--X’s turn-- 
|O|X| | 
------- |||| ------- |||| ------- 

--O’s turn-- 
|O|X| | 
------- 
| |O| | 
------- 
|||| 
------- 
--X’s turn-- 
|O|X| | 
------- 
| |O| | 
------- 
|X| | | 
______ 
—O’s turn— 
|O|X| | 
------- 
| |O| | 
------- 
|X| |O| 
O wins!

Comment: It's supposed to be vertical in the above response FYI.  I can't post it that way on this site, but it does appear vertical in the output in Java.

Comment: run: 
| | | | 
------ 

| | | | 
------ 

| | | | 
------ 


-0's turn-

Comment: Again it is vertical in the output in Java.  I can post it that way on this site FYI.

Comment: What does else if (gameboard [0][0]== && " "()) [0][0] mean though? What were you trying to express with each of those statements?

Comment: @Doug for example, what does == && mean or " "()?

Comment: == means 'equal to'.  The empty quote " " was for the 'empty' section of the tic tac toe board.  The [0] [0] is 'O'.  I am trying to express X wins, O wins, whether the board is empty through the entire board.

Comment: @Doug In order to test that, you'll have to check multiple array indices or write a LINQ query of some kind - there's not a single syntax that means "*x* is true of the entire array."

Comment: I'm using Netbeans though.  Basically my current winortie method is completely wrong.  I can't seem to figure out what code to put in to get it to compile correctly.

Comment: @Doug Sorry, Freudian slip with LINQ, that's a .NET thing. Some of the new Java 8 features might be helpful, or you could always use a "for" loop. Point being that it's not really possible to express what you're trying to express using only a single line of keywords like you're trying to do here, it's not really built into the language.

Comment: Well this is frustrating.  You see I have been working on this project (as a whole) since November.  I have been working on the winortie method for the past 2 months.  The entire code I have at the beginning of this thread is what I have been given. I am to figure out what to put in the winortie method, then getting the code to compile correctly.  I have attempted several different 'codes' only to be wrong.

Comment: I have seen examples of if statements for the winortie method for example...  (game board [0][0] == game board [0][1] && game board [0] [0] == game board [0] [2] && game board [0] [0] != 0) { winner = game board [0] [0];

Comment: Try not to think of encoding the entire algorithm in a single line like that - for example, there isn't really a "built-in" syntax to make statements about an entire collection. (That kind of thing is actually a *lot* easier to do in C# than in Java because of LINQ - hence the Freudian slip on my part).

Comment: Also I have been guided/told that an "if" statement is what I need to do.  So confused.

Comment: Right, the syntax you have in the comment is perfectly sensible - you're comparing specific *items* in the array to other specific items in the array. Think about how you'd apply that kind of reasoning to the entire array.

Comment: So in the main method where there is an if/else statement, needs to match what I have in the winortie method?

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience by the way.